need books about proving heuristic connectivity
In this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqyyFjZBDvw Van Hentenryck teaches that heuristics can be "connected", meaning that you can prove that the heuristic can attain the global optimum via well-chosen moves (if it happens to get lucky on its random choices). He shows how to prove that a heuristic is connected.
I looked through textbooks at What is good introductory literature on (meta)heuristics? . The Metaheuristics book by Talbi uses the word "connexity" briefly. That seems to be the same concept? The other Metaheuristics book by Duarte et al also mentions connectivity briefly. However, I don't see any of them discussing the origin of this concept or how to do the proofs. What book or article contains instructions on proving that heuristics are connected? What's the source of this idea? Does it go by any other name?

Interesting. On "if it happens to get lucky on its random choices": some MH implementations allow selecting moves that break hard constraints, mostly theoretically. Those could in theory be lucky on their random choices and alway be able to reach the global optimum. But they don't in practice.
Taking that a step further, what about heavy weight soft constraints? When do we need to expand the neighborhood (= add more elaborate move types) to workaround the walls of hard and heavy soft constraints?
